# Is there any sdk or kit to handle microsoft office formats in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a universal document editor, annotator and what not I am putting everything together. I am able to do almost all the stuff I want with pdf files, but what about MS-Office formats?? Is there any SDK or something to do it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is an Library to open Excel files known as [LibXLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxls/)

to display Word documents i would recommend you to user UIWebView as it can handle word files.

If you dont want to use UIWebView then you can use [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for Word, PDF files and ppt files.

Tutorial can be found [here](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-qlpreviewcontroller.html)

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav, I am looking for some parser kinda thing, that will list me pages/slides/pages in ppt/excel/word. So that I can capture them, save them as .png's to manipulate them.

Comment: But it cannot open newer version of file format like  .docx, .xlsx etc.