# How to open excel sheet in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel

I am beginner in Objective C and iOS. I have a doubt how can we open an excel sheet in our app. The question is that if i click on a button then excel sheet should be open.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

To add to @rckoenes answer, these are the files format supported by `UIWebview`:

```
Excel (.xls)

Keynote (.key.zip)

Numbers (.numbers.zip)

Pages (.pages.zip)

PDF (.pdf)

Powerpoint (.ppt)

Word (.doc)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)

Rich Text Format Directory (.rtfd.zip)

Keynote '09 (.key)

Numbers '09 (.numbers)

Pages '09 (.pages)
```

Here is the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UIWebView` class description

Answer (score 2):

Just load the excel sheet in a webview, this will load the excel sheet and the user is able to view it.

Answer (score 2):

you can open excel sheets using [LibXLS](http://libxls.sourceforge.net/)

I have answered similar question here too:

[Is there any sdk or kit to handle microsoft office formats in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153112/is-there-any-sdk-or-kit-to-handle-microsoft-office-formats-in-ios/14164480#14164480)

Comment: Great answer in your other post, the `QLPreviewController` is great option for this.